# How to XCTAssertEqual NSArray with custom objects?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, nsarray, xctest

This is my h file

```
@class TBL_CardView;

@interface TBL_CardsOnTableView: NSObject

- (CGPoint) addCard:(TBL_CardView *)cardView didFailWithError:(NSError **)error;
- (unsigned int) numberOfCardOnTable;

- (NSArray*) cardsOnTableWithPosition;

@end

@interface TBL_CardOnTableWithPosition: NSObject

- (instancetype)initWithCardView:(TBL_CardView*) cardView  withPosition:(NSUInteger) position;

@property(readonly) TBL_CardView*  card;
@property(readonly) NSUInteger position;

@end
```

in m file I do

```
- (NSArray*) cardsOnTableWithPosition
{
    return (NSArray*) _cardsOnTable;
}
```

_cardsOnTable is

```
NSMutableArray *_cardsOnTable;
_cardsOnTable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:8];
```

and I add new object with this code:

```
TBL_CardOnTableWithPosition* cvwp = [[TBL_CardOnTableWithPosition alloc] initWithCardView:cardView withPosition:avalableLocation] ;

[_cardsOnTable addObject:cvwp];
```

And this is how I test in Unit Test

```
[table cardsOnTableWithPosition];
TBL_CardOnTableWithPosition* cvwp1 = [[TBL_CardOnTableWithPosition alloc] initWithCardView:cardView1 withPosition:1] ;
NSLog(@"%@", [table cardsOnTableWithPosition]);

NSArray* array = [table cardsOnTableWithPosition];
NSArray * a = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:@[cvwp1]];
NSArray * d = [table cardsOnTableWithPosition];
XCTAssertEqual(a, d); // FAILD, but this I am expecting to failed 
XCTAssertEqualObjects(a, d);  // FAILD
XCTAssertEqualObjects(@[cvwp1], [table cardsOnTableWithPosition]);  // FAILD

XCTAssertTrue([a isEqualToArray:d]); // FAILD
```

In debuger objects a and d are same, but I can to find way how to test it in Unit test.
Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.

I needed to implement **- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object**
in my custom objects.

Comment: Don't forget to implement `-hash` as well.